# Backgroung image in Xubuntu (how to set up)

Tags: xubuntu

How to set up an image that I have on my workstation as a background in Xubuntu?

Comment: Right click>Desktop settings>Change the folder(down left)>Select image.

Comment: right! please answer the question so I can vote it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @kortewegdevries

`Right click`>`Desktop settings`>`Change the folder(down left)`>`Select image`